# Command to copy only folder with files

Tags: command-line, directory

I have this types of folders

```
folder A
  |
  -folder A
     |
     - 3files

folder B
  |
  -folder B
     |
     - no files
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKZvT.png]

child folders A and B have same name of parent folder A or B. Parent folder are in the same directory
**I want to copy only child folder with files** to another directory
How command can I use in Ubuntu 14 ?

Comment: So you want to copy a folder? Just to `cp -R /path/to/foldername /path/to/destination`.

Comment: What about folders with only folders?

Comment: I want copy 1st folders level that contains only 2nd folders with files

Comment: Asid from what Jacob Vlijm remarked (i.e. what about folders containing only folders? e.g. should `folder b/folder b/` be copied if containing just a, say, `folder b/folder b/folder b` folder but no other files?), "I want copy 1st folders level that contains only 2nd folders with files": from your wording it seems like you want to copy 2nd level folders which contains at least one file; in both cases my answer would be wrong, because it will copy any 2nd level folder containing either a single folder or a single file (i.e. any 2nd level folder containing anything).Can you clarify these points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Mind that this will copy also folders containing just folders, and not just folders containing at least one file. Not sure if that's exactly what you're looking for; in any case I'll leave this in case it could be useful to someone else.*

Using `find`:

```
find source -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -not -empty -exec mv {} target \;
```

- `source`: searches in `source/`
- `-mindepth 2`: searches starting from the second level of the specified directory hierarchy
- `-maxdepth 2`: searches stopping at the second level of the specified directory hierarchy
- `-type d`: searches only for directories
- `-not`: negates the following condition / action
- `-empty`: searches only for empty folders
- `-exec [...]`: for each result, executes the following command
- `mv {} target \;`: moves each result to `target/`

```
user@debian ~/tmp % tree
.
├── source
│   ├── folder A
│   │   └── folder A
│   │       ├── file1
│   │       ├── file2
│   │       └── file3
│   └── folder B
│       └── folder B
└── target

6 directories, 3 files
user@debian ~/tmp % find source -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -not -empty -exec mv {} target \; 
user@debian ~/tmp % tree
.
├── source
│   ├── folder A
│   └── folder B
│       └── folder B
└── target
    └── folder A
        ├── file1
        ├── file2
        └── file3

6 directories, 3 files
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cp -r /folderA/folderA /newdestination/
```

Command `cp` copies files or directories, and here is followed by `-r`, which recursively copies child directories in your destination. Pay attention to slashes after path or their absence. More on copying [here](http://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/cp.htm).

Comment: is there a way to copy only 2nd level-folders with files or should I use another application? Because your command and your link is valid only for a single folder copying

Comment: Command `cp` can work this way: `cp -r folderA/ folderB/ destination/`. Here, you have first two (folderA and folderB) copied into the third (destination).